# How to store long commands in environment variables in Linux?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, docker, environment-variables

I want to simply run the long command below.

```bash
docker ps -a --format "table {{.Image}}\t{{.Ports}}"
```

```bash
export view='docker ps -a --format "table {{.Image}}\t{{.Ports}}"'
```

### test

```bash
echo $view
docker ps -a --format "table {{.Image}}\t{{.Ports}}"
```

### Env Variable Exec

```bash
$view
```

### Result end Error code

But it runs like below.

```bash
"docker ps" accepts no argumets.
See 'docker ps --help'

Usage: docker ps [OPTIONS]

List containers
```

In short, can't save such long code as an environment variable?

and If possible, can I know another way?

Comment: Why don't you use Bash "aliases": https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should save as array and quote correctly. Only then you can be sure that it expands correctly.

```bash
cmd=("docker" "ps" "-a" "--format" "table {{.Images}}\t{{.Ports}}")
"${cmd[@]}"
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer for the answer to my question :D

Comment: thank you for your reply. It's resolved.
But the above command doesn't work.
It would be appreciated if you could correct the typo with the command below.

Comment: cmd=("docker" "ps" "-a" "--format" "table {{.Image}}\t{{.Ports}}")

Comment: oh..  sorry I'm wrong . I need to fix it. images -> image